# jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode - for DTD html 4.0 transitional <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

Tags: html, dtd, doctype, quirks-mode, jquery-migrate

I have below tag in my aspx page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

When I did jquery migrate , I am getting jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode

I referred https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/sgml/loosedtd.html, since its EXPERIMENTAL version of the HTML 4.0, so its considering the doc in Quirk mode

I thought to change to DTD of 4.01 but changes would be on multiple pages, please suggest some other way to handle it